# What is the full way to solve this sigma notation problem?

Tags: calculus

I found this question and found it very interesting,
$\lim_{k\to\infty\ }4\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{2n+1}$
How to solve it?

Comment: First I noticed that it's very similar to a well known formula for pi. (Leibniz series)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @coudy the OP's bounds are from $1$ to $k$ while the link you provide is for $0$ to $\infty$

Comment: @coudy I didn't see the limit part. So I guess it is a duplcate.

Comment: @KamalSaleh is there is a closed form if it is not infinite series ? I know this make a function $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^k\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1} x^{k+1}}{2k+1}$ and differentiate it then sum the alternating geometric series then integrate it back but does the integral can be done without special functions

Answer (score 3):

Start with $$\log (1-x) = -x -\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3} - \cdots$$

$$\log (1+x) = x -\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3} - \cdots$$

so that $$\frac{1}{2ix}\left[\log(1+ix)-\log(1-ix) \right] = 1-\frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{x^4}{5} - \cdots$$

$$ 4\left( 1-\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \cdots \right) = \frac{2}{i}\left[\log(1+i)-\log(1-i) \right]$$

$$\phantom{ 4\left( 1-\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \cdots \right)} = \frac{2}{i}\log\frac{1+i}{1-i} $$

$$\phantom{ 4\left( 1-\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \cdots \right)} = \frac{2}{i}\log i $$

$$\phantom{ 4\left( 1-\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \cdots \right)} = \pi.$$